# I do not understand the function

Tags: javascript

I do not understand the function fromToFn(), 
in my example there is no function with that name,

I do not understand my example

Example:

```js
var fromTo = function fromTo(i,limit){
        return function(){
            var next = i;
            if(i<limit){
                i += 1;
                return next;
            }
            return undefined;
        }
    }
var collect = function collect(fromToFn,array){
        return function (){
            var value = fromToFn();
            if (value !== undefined){
                array.push(value);
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    var array = [];
    var col = collect(fromTo(0,2),array);
    
    col(); //returns 0
    col(); //returns 1
    col(); //returns undefined
    console.log(array); //returns [0,1]
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok i sorry

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand the function fromToFn(), in my example there is no function with that name

That's true, but it doesn't matter. Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, references to them can be passed around in variables, properties, and parameters.

`fromToFn` is the name of a parameter in the `collect` function:

```
var collect = function collect(fromToFn,array){
// ----------------------------^
```

So if we pass a function into `collect`, we can use it within `collect` via that parameter.

The code *does* pass a function into `collect`, here:

```
var col = collect(fromTo(0,2),array);
```

...because `fromTo(0, 2)` *returns* a function, which is then passed into `collect`. To be very clear, because there are a couple of things going on, the function being passed into `collect` is **not** `fromTo`, it's the function `fromTo` returns. That line can be written:

```
var functionToPassToCollect = fromTo(0,2);
var col = collect(functionToPassToCollect,array);
```

Here's a simpler example demonstrating using a parameter to call a function passed in:

```js
function example(f) {
    f();
}
function callMe() {
    console.log("callMe was called");
}

example(callMe);
```

Comment: okey i sorry, How to delete this question?

Comment: @rn3w: You don't need to, it's a perfectly reasonable question. But if you want to, you'll need to flag it and ask a moderator to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
var col = collect(fromTo(0,2),array);
```

You're calling the `collect` function and the first argument you pass is `fromTo(0,2)`.

The `fromTo` function, when called, returns a function. So `fromToFn`, in the call to `collect`, is a function and can be called too:

```
var value = fromToFn();
```

`fromTo` and `collect` handle functions, they're called ["higher-order" functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). This is possible in JavaScript because in JavaScript functions are first-class values, they can be assigned to variables like other types of values (see [First-Class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)).

In this specific case, the point of the function returned by `fromTo` is that it can uses the variables of the `fromTo` scope, it's called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Answer (score 0):

fromToFn is the function that sent to the 'collect' function as parameter :

```
function collect(fromToFn,array);
```

and you send the fromTo function :

```
collect(fromTo(0,2),array)
```